# Требуется заменить следующий код JavaScript на конструкцию JQuery (желательно одной строкой)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var element = document.getElementById('id-of-element');
element.setAttribute('data-value', 'data-for-element');
element.style.color = 'red';
element.innerHTML('<p>html code</p>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#id-of-element')
  .data({"data-value": "data-for-element"})
  .css({"color": "red"})
  .html("<p>html code</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#id-of-element").attr('data-value', 'data-for-element').css('color ', 'red').append('<p>html code</p>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="id-of-element"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#id-of-element").attr("data-value","data-for-element").css("color","red").html("<p>html code</p>");
```